InputError: List index out of range
I am trying to recognise the text from the uploaded image, for some images; my GUI is returning positive response, but for some other images: it is giving IndexError: list index out of range. I am using easyocr for image recognition. I am attaching my code for the same.
Error is raising in line print("Number Plate:", results[0][1])
import easyocr


def OCR(path, filename):
    img = np.array(load_img(path))
    coords = object_detection(path, filename)
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = coords[0]
    roi = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    roi_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("./static/roi/{}".format(filename), roi_bgr)
    reader = easyocr.Reader(["en"])
    results = reader.readertext(roi)
    print("Number Plate:", results[0][1])
    return results[0][1]


If you're getting an IndexError for results, I'd imagine the OCR process didn't find anything.
You might want to debug with a print(results), and then add a guard:
if results:
    return results[0][1]
return None

so the function will return None if there are no results.
